# How can I log crashes/errors for Ionic 4 app?

Tags: angular, cordova, logging, ionic4

Maybe you'd suggest any framework to integrate or anything else.
I would really appreciate your help.
What i need:
- log native app crashes
- log javascript errors
- send part of the js logs to me
- analytics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For logging native crashes you can use

- [Crashlytics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics)
- [Sentry](https://sentry.io)
- [Instabug](https://instabug.com/)

For logging javascript crashes you can use

- [Sentry](https://sentry.io)

Comment: Thank you. I used Sentry in my case and it works perfect.